# How can I move my arm without affecting the body?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

[image: This is what it should look like]
[image: This is what my character looks like]

I´m new to blender, can anybody help me? (It should look like in the upper picture)

Comment: Hi. In future, please [edit] the question instead of deleting and re-asking it.

Comment: ok, sorry, I´m new here : )

Comment: You can correct the influences in Weight Paint Mode. In Object Mode select the armature first, then (while holding the shift key) select the mesh and go to Weight Paint Mode. Select the ominous bone and add or subtract the weith on the affected area.